# Jupyterlab: "Error displaying widget: model not found" - Step-by-step instructions on how to debug

Tags: jupyter-lab, jupyter-extensions, jupyter-widget

When installing new jupyterlab extensions or widgets, a common error displayed is:
`Error displaying widget: model not found`.
The console displayed cryptic error messages such as:
`Could not instantiate widget`, `Error: Could not create a model.`, `Module @jupyter-widgets/base, semver range ^2.0.0 is not registered as a widget module`.
The solution proposed is generally "uninstall and re-install".

I would like to know

- How to actually debug this error?
- What does "model not found" mean?
- Where is Jupyter looking for the model?
- What is a "semver-range" and how can I see what exactly was not registered as a widget module?
- Can a user do something to "register the model"?
- Can we get Jupyter or JS to display what folders it is looking for information and where they are configured?

This error is so common with a large number of widgets that it would be helpful to show people what it actually means and how to investigate it.